# Does Google Closure Templates support extending templates

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

E.g. I want my page templates page1.soy, page2.soy, pagex.soy to extend my base.soy template which includes a header and footer.

Is this supported?

This is common functionality in e.g. Django and Jinja2 template engines.

Answer (score 1):

In closure, composition is more natural than hierarchy. I.e., have a page component to manage the header and footer with (or add a header/footer component to.) Then you can set the pageContent area (another component) on the page component.

You could also mimic hierarchy by creating a page template which includes a header / footer and then a specific content template based on a property passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try this:

```
{namespace sample}

/**
 * Layout
 * @param title
 * @param body
 */
{template .base}
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      {$body}
    </body>
  </html>
{/template}

/**
 * Page example
 */
{template .page1}
  {call .base}
    {param title}
      Sample Title
    {/param}
    {param body}
      Sample body
    {/param}
  {/call}
{/template}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458346/using-main-layout-template-in-closure-templates